# How to read response value from an ASP.NET Core Web API call

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an ASP.NET Core Web API endpoint as shown here in my first API. This endpoint works fine returns expected values

```
public ActionResult PostSchoolQuery(SchoolQueryModel schoolQueryModel)
{
    SchoolListResponseModel schoolListResponseModel = new SchoolListResponseModel();
    // some code 
    return Ok(schoolListResponseModel);
}
```

The response model:

```
public class SchoolListResponseModel
{
    public List<School> SchoolList { get; set; }
}
```

I've called this above endpoint in my second API. There I'm facing some issue while receive the response values.

```
public async Task<SchoolListResponseModel> GetUserSchools(JObject getSchoolsModel)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {                
        var responseTask = await client.PostAsJsonAsync( requestUrl, getSchoolsModel);

        if (responseTask.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            schoolResponse = responseTask.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            // O this line I'm facing issue 
            schoolListResponseModel = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(schoolResponse);
        }
    }
}
```

Here on the last line, I'm getting this error

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'Models' in C# .NET

Please let me know how to fix this. Thanks

Comment: Show us the class definition for `School` , and please also show the contents of your `schoolResponse` string that you get from the first API call

Comment: what is the datatype of `schoolResponse`?

Answer (score 2):

you are trying implicitly convert a string to model object, you have to deserialize it first.

```
SchoolListResponseModel schoolListResponseModel = null;

using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var responseTask = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(requestUrl, getSchoolsModel);

    if (responseTask.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var schoolResponse = await responseTask.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        schoolListResponseModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SchoolListResponseModel>(schoolResponse);
    }
}

return schoolListResponseModel;
```

Comment: Yes i tried this too ... but I'm getting null values in schoolListResponseModel  , but in first api it returns expected values.. do you have any suggestions for it ?

Comment: hmm there could be a couple reasons something i continually do is forget to provide the class with getters and setters.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, also you can add log after reading the content string to confirm what you are deserializing.

```
SchoolListResponseModel schoolListResponseModel = new SchoolListResponseModel();

using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {                
        var responseTask = await client.PostAsJsonAsync( requestUrl, getSchoolsModel);

        if (responseTask.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string schoolResponse = await responseTask.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            //You can temporarily log the schoolResponse here to confirm you get the SchoolListResponseModel
            schoolListResponseModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SchoolListResponseModel>(schoolResponse);
        }
    }
```